# Who wrote the game 'The Pits'?

Tags: gaming-history, text-adventure, the-pits

I'm looking for info on a game called 'The Pits', a text based adventure game which was on "[The Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Source_(online_service))", a BBS computer system in the early 80s.

Who wrote this game? Was it ever ported to more modern computers (Linux or Windows)?

Note that the game in question is a text based game and not a graphics game.

Comment: I have edited this to incorporate info that was in the comments & to remove the 100% off-topic point about finding the source code. Up to the community if you want to reopen or not, I won't override that consensus, not today at least :)

Answer (score 9):

The Pits was written by Jim Walters, using the ADV550 engine.  The only lead on his location is that he moved to California around 20 years ago.  It's likely that the source is nowhere to be found, unless you can find him.  I too would like to find it.

---

According to the link provided by Mark Hurd below from [Copyright Encyclopedia](http://www.copyrightencyclopedia.com/funding-michigan-k-12-educational-adequacy-without/#id16565940#ixzz4HXpgQU3e):

> - **Type of Work:**
>     Machine-readable work or computer program
> - **Registration Number / Date:**
>     TXu000039634 / 1980-03-10
> - **Date of Creation:**
>     1980
> - **Title:**
>     The Pits : an interactive fantasy game / conceived and written by Jim Walters [i.e. James Burrell Walters, Jr.] and Dave Broadhurst [i.e. David Martin Broadhurst]
> - **Edition:**
>     Revision 6.65.
> - **Description:**
>     Printout.
> - **Copyright Claimant:**
>     James B. Walters & David M. Broadhurst
> - **Names:**
>
>   - David Martin Broadhurst 1957-
>   - Walters, James Burrell, Jr., 1959-
>   - Dave Broadhurst
>   - Jim Walters (18 documents)
> - example document: My heart goes out to you

Comment: Incidentally, how do you know this information? (Citation needed. :))

Comment: According to [this link](http://www.copyrightencyclopedia.com/funding-michigan-k-12-educational-adequacy-without/#id16565940) there was a "Dave Broadhurst" involved too.