# Who made the game "Torus" in the 1990s?

Tags: gaming-history, torus

I'm trying to find the publisher of a game from the early 1990s called "Torus".

It was a 2d realtime puzzle game on DOS or Windows 3.x.  Spinning rings of different colors fell from above onto spikes at the bottom of the screen.

You could manipulate the order of the rings on the spikes.  The goal was to match the colors to get some pattern (possibly three in a row) so they would go away and make room for more fallen rings.

Comment: Just want to note: This is not a game-id question. OP is asking for the *Developer* of the game, not the game itself.

Comment: @Ben - Yeah I think these have generally been considered on-topic. At least, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/29155/28182) was positively received & reopened after I cleaned it up.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any online links or info about that *specific* 'Torus' game yet. I would probably have drawn the conclusion that it doesn't exist, except that I found [this reimplementation](https://sourceforge.net/p/ktorus/wiki/Home/) which explicitly called out that it was *"inspired by Torus for DOS(R)."*

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the game was developed and published by Yunsung in 1996 based on the information I found at the links below which also contain this video.

You can see at the end there is the title screen and name Yunsung is at the bottom. Although the Games Database  doesn't list Torus as a game by Yunsung all the other games listed are published and developed by Yunsung leading me to believe that it was likely that Torus was the same.

Its also possible that this was the developer and maker of the original arcade cabinet and that the DOS version was converted and/or published by someone else.

[archive.com](https://archive.org/details/youtube-QA1ziq-mzyo)

[GamesDatabase.org](https://www.gamesdatabase.org/all_developer_games-yun_sung)